# I need to import/require a node module - but it contains a wasm file greater than 4kb. My application is an electron app. How can I make this work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, node-modules

I am trying to import essentia.js. When running, any attempt to import the module results in

> "WebAssembly.Compile is disallowed on the main thread, if the buffer size is larger than 4KB. Use WebAssembly.compile, or compile on a worker thread."

I tried making a worker, but realized you cannot import node modules.

is it possible to handle npm imports if the wasm file is greater than 4kb? How might I do this?

For reference, I am trying to use functions from essentia.js on an Electron application. I successfully ran a test function with node test.js via cmd; not realizing it would fail on Electron.

Essentia.js has a tutorial, where they say:

> Note: You shouldn't import the essentia-wasm.module.js on the main thread. The ideal way is to use it along with the AudioWorklet design pattern or with WebWorkers. Also, it is recommended to use local files instead of CDN in production.
> https://mtg.github.io/essentia.js/docs/api/tutorial-1.%20Getting%20Started.html

However, I do not know how to do this. I've been trying to understand what I have to do, but its quite a lot to take in.

My goal is to call Essentia functions for bpm and key analysis - but I'm very new to multithreading.

For instance, I need essentia.js-core - but this file requires the wasm file. How do I prepare the wasm file so that I may use the other files? Is this possible?

In retrospect, electron was probably not the greatest design choice - but we opted for familiarity. I know that nodeJS isn't the problem - it's the fact that this application essentially runs on a chrome browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

electron can support node modules in their web workers.

In webPreferences, ensure that nodeIntegrationInWorker: true is set.

for instance

```
Main.mainWindow = new Main.BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600, webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true, enableRemoteModule: true, nodeIntegrationInWorker: true} });
```

After doing this, you may require node modules within your worker.js file

You must also ensure that your worker's type is like so:

```
const worker = new Worker('./someWorker.js', { type: 'module' });
```

I could then do the following

```
   await worker.postMessage(audioData);

   worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
      console.log(`page got message: ${data}`);      
   };
```

which does the following in my worker file

```
essentia = require('essentia.js');

addEventListener('message', e => {
  console.log(e.data);

  let audio = e.data.channelData[0];
  let inputSignalVector = essentia.arrayToVector(audio);
  let key = essentia.KeyExtractor(inputSignalVector);

  console.log("working");

  postMessage(key);

});
```

In my worker, I use a node module to estimate the key of an audio buffer I passed. This is proof of a node module being required in an electron worker.